# Qt and sound processing

Tags: c++, qt, audio, process

I need to increase tempo of voice in sound file. (This effect will speed up the playing but leave the original tempo). Any ways to do this with c++ and Qt media library? Thanks.

Any links are excepted.

Comment: If you speed up a sound the tempo will increase. Can you be more specific? Are you referring to pitch shifting or something?

Comment: @cyco130 Let's think that I do need Pinch and Tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/).

Comment: Dear Ockonal and cyco130: Does any of you care explaining how SoundTouch is used/linked with C++ and/or Qt? It'll help others understand things better.

Comment: I haven't tried it but since they don't supply any pre-compiled libraries, I'm guessing you'd have to download the source code, build it using the supplied make/project files and link against it as with any other library in your system. By the way, SoundTouch has nothing to do with Qt directly, it's just a C++ library.

Answer (score 1):

Qt has hardly any sound processing capabilities, so nothing as advanced as what the original poster wants exists in it.

Answer (score 0):

Qt cannot do what you want.  Moreover, pitch-shifting is computationally intensive task involving fast Fourier transforms and then some trickery to counteract the phase shifting.  Couple [FFTW3](http://www.fftw.org/) with [this](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/) excellent guide, and you can do it.